# Div has scroll bar

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/LUfgY/

It doesn't show it there but if that code is run on normal browser, it would produce scroll bars within the parent div.

How do I remove that scroll bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#container {
    overflow:hidden; /* change to hidden */
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:37px;
    height: 100%;
    width:875px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 30 30px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 30 0 30px 5px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 30 30px 5px #999;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-top-style:none;
}
#child1 {
    overflow:hidden; /* change to hidden */
    min-height:150px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
    background-color:#eee;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Changing `auto` to `hidden` on `#container` doesn't make a difference?  Are you sure?  What browser is this in?  I just tried in FF8 and it most definitely gets rid of the scroll bar there.

Comment: Ok, it is working now. Thanks, but will it hide content if the content stretches down?

Comment: Yup..  If you don't want that, you can use `visible` instead of `hidden`.  That will allow it to draw outside the container.  Just remove the `overflow` attribute completely if you want it to expand as needed (which is the default behavior).

Comment: so remove it from both container and child1?

Comment: Correct.  I doubt it made a difference to begin with in `child1` though.

Answer (score 4):

In most browsers `overflow:auto` causes a scrollbar to be provided for overflowing boxes. Change the according div(s) to `overflow:hidden`

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUfgY/4/) should work.

Comment: the scrollbars are still being produced inside the parent div.

Comment: Did you change `overflow` to `hidden` in both `container` and `child1`?

Comment: `child1` probably doesn't matter since it only has a min-height, it'll just expand instead of scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS overflow property to control the scroll bars:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: I almost linked to that but I assumed I would get flamed for referencing w3schools

Comment: Yeah, but it's simple documentation. @Mike Christensen did the right answer by actually typing out the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have overflow:auto on everything? no wonder you get scroll bars.

Here's a decent overflow reference:
http://css-tricks.com/2833-the-css-overflow-property/

Otherwise, just declare overflow:hidden, overflow-x:hidden or overflow-y:hidden